istio DestinationRule outlineDection evict pod which response 503 error but pod is health
I am try to use DestinationRule outlineDection to limit cross zone on cloud.
Since we have lot of services on k8s, so In the DR shown as below, we use wildcard on host field to limit all traffic in specific namespace will not cross zone.
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: DestinationRule
metadata:
  name: express-test-http-poc
  namespace: ericw-ns-poc
spec:
  host: "*"
  trafficPolicy:
    outlierDetection:
      consecutive5xxErrors: 1
      interval: 5s
      baseEjectionTime: 5s
      maxEjectionPercent: 100

Here is my architecture.
Suppose there are an http-clinet which will call another services(good-server& bad-server) based on the path in URL.
And the http clinet will response the result from another services(good-server& bad-server) directly.
We found that when http-client receive response from bad server and response to client, it will cause http-client pods are evicted even if http-client is healthy.
I wonder know is there config of istio could prevent http-client pods from being evicted?
Thanks.

The reason of http-client-pod eviction is host: "*".
Architecture image only describes pods and traffic between them. I guess that there must be services infront of pods.
Could you try with target service name instead of * as host configuration?
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: DestinationRule
metadata:
  name: express-test-http-poc
  namespace: ericw-ns-poc
spec:
  host: "service name of pods to be controlled by circuit breaker"
  trafficPolicy:
    outlierDetection:
      consecutive5xxErrors: 1
      interval: 5s
      baseEjectionTime: 5s
      maxEjectionPercent: 100

